# Скрыть текст через 3 дня

Tags: php

На сайте есть скрипт комментариев к новостям. Нужно скрыть все комментарии через 3 дня после публикации новости.

Есть поле $date_news с датой новости в UNIX формате. Как мне в условии сделать так, чтобы через 3 дня скрылись комментарии (который находятся в переменной $comments)?

Я думал сделать так, типа `if (дата_новости+3дня <= текущей_даты)` Но не знаю как это реализовать. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Т.к. комментарии по-любому хранятся в БД, и то надо изначально вытаскивать и БД комментарии, которые не менее трёхдневной давности. Манипуляции в PHP тут не нужны

Comment: нет, мне нужно именно то, что я написал. Комментарии все записаны в переменную.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$a_time = '1611677004'; //дата новости
$b_time = '272944'; // 3 дня в unixtime
$a_b_time = $a_time + $b_time; // сложение даты новости и 3 дня
$time_today = time(); // текущая дата в unixtime

if ($a_b_time <= $time_today) {echo 'КОММЕНТАРИИ СКРЫТЫ';}
else {echo 'КОММЕНТАРИИ ОТОБРАЖЕНЫ';}
?>
```